# How to pass one extra variable to listview in yii2

Tags: php, listview, yii, yii2

I am new in yii2 and i need to have pass two variable to listview.my listview is as below.

```
ListView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $tripMembers,
       'id' => '_trip_member_items',
       'itemView' => '_members_items',
       'itemOptions' => ['tag' => false],
       'summary' => '',
       'emptyText' => '',
       'options' => ['class' => 'details-list', 'tag' => 'ul']
   ]);
```

Please help me .Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link may be helpful http://www.codevoila.com/post/4/yii2-listview-example

Comment: Thanks @Bikash,but found the solution.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass one more variable as below,

```
ListView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $tripMembers,
       'id' => '_trip_member_items',
       'itemView' => '_members_items',
       'itemOptions' => ['tag' => false],
       'summary' => '',
       'emptyText' => '',
       'options' => ['class' => 'details-list', 'tag' => 'ul'],
      'viewParams'=>['id'=>'121'],
   ]);
```

Hope it will help to someone else also